# Call UpdateBookmark & useAforB as Boolean code assistance

Tags: vba, call, ms-word, userform, autofill

I've been putting some code together with some help from people on this website. I've run into a bit of a snag - Im using the `Call UpdateBookmark` function to replace previously entered information into the word document and im having issues implementing this into my existing code.

```
Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
    Dim useAforB As Boolean
    useAforB = CheckBox1.Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
        Call UpdateBookmark("Lodge", ComboBoxLodge.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Form", tbForm.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Form2", tbForm.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("AGN", tbGN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("AFN", tbFN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LGN", useAforB, _
                                     tbGN.Value, TBLPGN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("RGN", useAforB, _
                                     tbGN.Value, TBLPGN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LFN", useAforB, _
                                     tbFN.Value, TBLPFN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("RFN", useAforB, _
                                     tbFN.Value, TBLPFN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("DOB", tbDOB.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LT", cbLT.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PN", tbPN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PN2", tbPN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PN3", tbPN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PN4", tbPN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Issued", tbissue.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Expiry", tbexpiry.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LTD", tbLTD.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LTD2", tbLTD.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Narrative", tbNarrative.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PRR", tbPRR.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Recommendation", cbRecommendation.Value)
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
End Sub


Sub UpdateBookmark(BookmarkToUpdate As String, TextAtBookmark As String)
   Dim BookmarkRange As Range
   Set BookmarkRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BookmarkToUpdate).Range
   BookmarkRange.Text = TextAtBookmark
   ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add BookmarkToUpdate, BookmarkRange

End Sub
```

I get an error which reads `Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch` whenever I try to run the code - is anyone able to give me some assistance?? Thanks guys.

***Entire code added for clarity***

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim en As Boolean
    en = Not CheckBox1.Value
    EnableControls Array(TBLPGN, TBLPFN), en

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then ComboBoxLodge.Value = "Applicant"
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then ComboBoxLodge.Value = "Lodging parent"

End Sub


'utility sub: enable/disable controls
Private Sub EnableControls(cons, bEnable As Boolean)
    Dim con
    For Each con In cons
        With con
            .Enabled = bEnable
            .BackColor = IIf(bEnable, vbWhite, RGB(200, 200, 200))
        End With
    Next con
End Sub
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
tbForm.Value = Null
tbFN.Value = Null
tbGN.Value = Null
tbdob.Value = Null
cbLT.Value = Null
tbPN.Value = Null
tbissue.Value = Null
tbexpiry.Value = Null
tbLTD.Value = Null
tbNarrative.Value = Null
tbPRR.Value = Null
cbRecommendation.Value = Null
CheckBox1.Value = False
ComboBoxLodge.Value = Null
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
    Dim useAforB As Boolean
    useAforB = CheckBox1.Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument
        Call UpdateBookmark("Lodge", ComboBoxLodge.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Form", tbForm.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Form2", tbForm.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("AGN", tbGN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("AFN", tbFN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LGN" useAforB _
                                     tbGN.Value, TBLPGN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("RGN", useAforB, _
                                     tbGN.Value, TBLPGN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LFN", useAforB, _
                                     tbFN.Value, TBLPFN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("RFN", useAforB, _
                                     tbFN.Value, TBLPFN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("DOB", tbdob.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LT", cbLT.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PN", tbPN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PN2", tbPN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PN3", tbPN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PN4", tbPN.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Issued", tbissue.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Expiry", tbexpiry.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LTD", tbLTD.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("LTD2", tbLTD.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Narrative", tbNarrative.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("PRR", tbPRR.Value)
        Call UpdateBookmark("Recommendation", cbRecommendation.Value)
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
End Sub


Sub UpdateBookmark(BookmarkToUpdate As String, TextAtBookmark As String)
   Dim BookmarkRange As Range
   Set BookmarkRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BookmarkToUpdate).Range
   BookmarkRange.Text = TextAtBookmark
   ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add BookmarkToUpdate, BookmarkRange

End Sub

Private Sub Tbform_Change()
    tbForm = UCase(tbForm)
End Sub


Private Sub Tbpn_Change()
    tbPN = UCase(tbPN)
End Sub


Private Sub tbPRR_Change()
    tbPRR = UCase(tbPRR)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With cbLT
        .AddItem "lost"
        .AddItem "stolen"
    End With
    With cbRecommendation
        .AddItem "I believe there is an entitlement to have the l/t flag turned off as the applicant has not contributed to the loss of Passport number: "
        .AddItem "I believe there is no entitlement to have the l/t flag turned off as the applicant has contributed to the loss of Passport number:  "
    End With
    With ComboBoxLodge
        .AddItem "Lodging parent"
        .AddItem "Applicant"
     End With
     With CheckBox1
        CheckBox1.Value = True
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: `UpdateBookmark` expect two String-type arguments, but in some cases you're passing four arguments: it's not clear what the intent is there.  Did you mean something like `Call UpdateBookmark("LGN", IIf(useAforB,
                                     tbGN.Value, TBLPGN.Value))` ?

Comment: hey @TimWilliams, tried your code and that has fixed it completely - you are a legend (want to put it down as an answer so I can choose your answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sub `UpdateBookmark` expect two String-type arguments, but in some cases you're passing four arguments: it's not clear what the intent is there.

Did you mean something like

```
Call UpdateBookmark("LGN", IIf(useAforB, tbGN.Value, TBLPGN.Value))
```

?

Comment: Perfect that is what I needed, thank you very much for your assistance :)